# c# how to load incoming soap1.2 message into xml dom

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I developing my first WCF webservice in which I need to load the incoming Soap message into the xml dom for processing but I cannot find out how to do that.
I'm trying:

```
namespace acdCM
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IResNotif
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [XmlSerializerFormat]
        XmlDocument OTA_HotelResNotifRQ();
    }
}

namespace acdCM
{

    public class ResNotif : IResNotif
    {
        public XmlDocument OTA_HotelResNotifRQ()
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapMessage.ToString());

            .......
        }
    }
}
```

which does not work at all because SoapMessage cannot be used as a string.

My problem is that I cannot find out how to make a string from the incoming SoapMessage so that I can load it into an XmlDocument.

Comment: Please read [ask] and explain what "does not work at all" means exactly.

Comment: Are you consuming/calling a soap service? Or are you creating a host service? On service contract, return type XmlDocument doesn't make sense.

Comment: @CodeCaster - hi, thanks for looking. I've edit my post somewhat - I hope my dilemma is now explained more clearly.

Comment: @loopedcode - hi there - I'm building a host service which receives Soap1.2 messages from a remote client, processes that input and returns a Soap response. I'm actually trying to convert/upgrade an asmx service which has done the same job for several years now, and that returns an XmlDocument, so that's why I'm trying it here. If my approach "doesn't make sense" I'd very sooooo grateful if you would explain why and show me how it should be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, now I can answer my own question.

To get the incoming soap message, I used

String rq = System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString();

then load it into an XmlDocument like this:

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.LoadXml(rq);